# can not detect the correct class when using Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am using **tensorflow** object detection API to train and detect my dataset. This dataset has 5 classes(every class has 50 images), and it contains two very similar classes(red and black). After the train process, I detected the test images and found that, the model always detects a target of red class as a target of black class, the other classes is detected as correct class.

I trained the model with `faster_rcnn_resnet101_breads.congfig`, and using `fine_tune_checkpoint.I` set the learning_rate to 0.003(the original is 0.0003).

Can you tell me what is wrong with my model, and how much the learning_rate should I set?

The compare result of my config file and samples config file:[compare result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B9oi.png)

train curves:[train curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoMsZ.png)

```
> black class: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWrlK.jpg
> red class: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuRjg.jpg
```

Comment: Perhaps you could post more details about your training curves, eval curves, what your images look like, etc?

Comment: @JonathanHuang thank you for your help! I just post the train curves, black class's image and red class's image. I do not run the eval.py directly, because I write a detect.py to detect the train set and test set.

Comment: Your dataset is rather small, this may be the primary reason. The network is probably not able to learn. You can start with a pre-trained model and fine tune on your dataset (only the last layers) + using data augmentation to increase the dataset size. You may need to train longer with a smaller learning rate.

Comment: @Blackberry thank you dude! But I started training from a pre-trained model and fine tune on my dataset always.  50 pictures per class is not enough?  I tested the model before,if the first 1000 steps without good results, the back of the training will only get worse.So, I just test the first 1000 steps now.

Comment: Do you have test curves too?

Comment: no, I just visualization the result on the images and print detect score for every class.